# Cannot get position of loaded json models

Tags: three.js, webgl

Here is an example json file for a simple rectangular box.

```
{

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "sourceFile"    : "BOX.obj",
        "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
        "vertices"      : 8,
        "faces"         : 6,
        "normals"       : 6,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : 4,
        "materials"     : 1
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials": [  {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "wire_135110008",
    "colorAmbient" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    "colorDiffuse" : [0.5294, 0.4314, 0.0314],
    "colorSpecular" : [0.35, 0.35, 0.35],
    "illumination" : 2,
    "specularCoef" : 32.0,
    "transparency" : 1.0
    }],

    "vertices": [-0.069100,0.041400,0.069200,-0.069100,0.041400,0.040600,-0.028100,0.041400,0.040600,-0.028100,0.041400,0.069200,-0.069100,0.077200,0.069200,-0.028100,0.077200,0.069200,-0.028100,0.077200,0.040600,-0.069100,0.077200,0.040600],

    "morphTargets": [],

    "morphColors": [],

    "normals": [0,-1,-0,0,1,-0,0,0,1,1,0,-0,0,0,-1,-1,0,-0],

    "colors": [],

    "uvs": [[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0]],

    "faces": [43,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,43,4,5,6,7,0,3,0,1,2,1,1,1,1,43,0,3,5,4,0,3,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,43,3,2,6,5,0,3,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,43,2,1,7,6,0,3,0,1,2,4,4,4,4,43,1,0,4,7,0,3,0,1,2,5,5,5,5]

}
```

And here is my code for loading the box above (no setting position statement for the loaded box):

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
jsonLoader.load('models/demo/BOX.js', function (geometry, materials) {
    var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, faceMaterial);

    // Add mesh to the scene
    box.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
    scene.add(box);
});
```

I tried to get its original positon after loading and I got problem. The position which I got with `$('#info').html(box.position.x + ', ' + box.position.y + ', ' + box.position.z);` is always `0, 0, 0` . (#info is a div element to show the result).
Could someone please help me to get the original position of the box (or any other models) after loading without manually setting its position?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `box.computeBoundingSphere ();` and then box.boundingSphere.center would contain the center of your model. Additionally you could use `computeBoundingBox().`

Comment: Thank you so much! But, 'box.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();' or 'box.geometry.computeBoundingBox();' are the most correct.